# DataFormatString in my Gridview does not work in SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, gridview, sharepoint-designer

I have a ASP.NET GridView that i created on a page through SharePoint Designer 2007.
For some reason it just does not want to work, why is that and how can i Fix it?

Funny thing, it worked on another SharePoint Server but not on the one i am working on now, so i know my code is fine, it must be something ells on the SharePoint Server maybe?

My Currency DataFormatStrings also dont want to work on my current SharePoint Server.

My DataFormatString for my Date field

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="c505_remdate" HeaderText="Remit. Advice Date" 
 SortExpression="c505_remdate" DataFormatString="{0:d/MM/yyyy}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does anything pop up in the log when you try and view your page? Do you just get a blank page when loading? Is it just the grid view that's missing? A little more detail might help uncover the problem.

Data format strings might get wonky if HtmlEncode is set to true. See the first note under "Remarks" here:

[system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

set the htmlencode="False" atribute in the field and that fixes it.
go figure